# What is the reason behind below mentioned error/exception while consuming travelport Universal api?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

I have a custom service class named as HotelClient (this class consumes Travelport's Universal API) with below code in one of the it's method:

```
        try
        {
            var httpHeaders = Helper.ReturnHttpHeader();
            hotelSearchclient.Endpoint.EndpointBehaviors.Add(new HttpHeadersEndpointBehavior(httpHeaders));

            hotelSearchAvailabilityResponse = hotelSearchclient.service(hotelSearchAvailabilityRequest);
        }
        catch (Exception se)
        {
            hotelSearchclient.Abort();
        }

        return hotelSearchAvailabilityResponse;
```

When I run the code I get caught in catch block with below message:

```
{"The provided URI scheme 'https' is invalid; expected 'http'.\r\nParameter name: via"}
```

and the api end point is "https://apac.universal-api.pp.travelport.com/B2BGateway/connect/uAPI/HotelService".

What is the reason behind this type of error and what can be general solution. Thank you all.

Comment: The error message says it all. You are calling the endpoint via https and not http also you are not passing the parameter "via"

Comment: Yes, your wright but I need specific answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In web.config/app.config, change

```
    <binding name="someService" /> to 

    <binding name="someService"  maxBufferPoolSize="524288"
        maxBufferSize="2147483646" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483646"
        transferMode="Buffered">
      <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Basic" proxyCredentialType="None"
            realm="AXIS" />
        <message clientCredentialType="Certificate" algorithmSuite="Default" />
      </security>
    </binding>
```

If above solution doesn't work, then check for your credential expiration.

Solution provided above violets DRY principle, so link 'https://pastebin.com/QFhTTCqF' has complete web.config content.

Comment: solved by adding security, transport and message tags inside binding tag for all service references.

Comment: I updated answer with DRY code implementation available in link mentioned in edited section. Hope this will help you.

Answer (score -1):

```
Read Write textFile

--------------------



       public void Loaddetails()
                {
                    List<string> inputList = new List<string>();
                    string path = @"H:\Desktop\Prj Local\TradeList.txt";

                    StreamReader strReader = new StreamReader(path);
                    string line = "";

                    while ((line = strReader.ReadLine())!= null)
                    {
                        if(line.Length>0)
                        {
                            inputList.Add(line);
                        }
                    }
                    List<TradeList> ValidList = new List<TradeList>();
                    List<TradeList> InvalidList = new List<TradeList>();
                    foreach (string lsttovalid in inputList)
                    {
                        DateTime outDate = new DateTime();
                        DateTime outMatDate = new DateTime();
                        string[] splist = lsttovalid.Split(',');

                        if (splist[0]!=null && splist[0].StartsWith("TR")&&System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(splist[1],@"^ISIN\d{3}$") &&
                            DateTime.TryParseExact(splist[2],"MM/dd/yyyy", null, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out outDate)&&
                            DateTime.TryParseExact(splist[3],"MM/dd/yyyy",null,System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out outMatDate)&&
                            outMatDate > outDate.AddYears(5)&& splist[4]!=null&& System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(splist[5],@"^[a-zA-Z]{3}$"))
                        {
                            TradeList vtd = new TradeList();

                            vtd.TradeId = splist[0];
                            vtd.TradeType = splist[1];
                            vtd.TradeDate = Convert.ToDateTime(splist[2]);
                            vtd.MaturityDate = Convert.ToDateTime(splist[3]);
                            vtd.Tradevalue = splist[4];
                            vtd.Currency = splist[5];
                            vtd.Money = Convert.ToInt32(splist[6]);

                            ValidList.Add(vtd);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            TradeList etd = new TradeList();

                            etd.TradeId = splist[0];
                            etd.TradeType = splist[1];
                            etd.TradeDate = Convert.ToDateTime(splist[2]);
                            etd.MaturityDate = Convert.ToDateTime(splist[3]);
                            etd.Tradevalue = splist[4];
                            etd.Currency = splist[5];
                            etd.Money = Convert.ToInt32(splist[6]);

                            InvalidList.Add(etd);
                        }
                    }

                    List<string> Invalid = new List<string>();

                    foreach (TradeList trd in InvalidList)
                    {
                        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                        sb.Append(trd.TradeId + ',');
                        sb.Append(trd.TradeType + ',');
                        sb.Append(Convert.ToDateTime(trd.TradeDate).ToShortDateString().ToString() + ',');
                        sb.Append(Convert.ToDateTime(trd.MaturityDate).ToShortDateString().ToString() + ',');
                        sb.Append(trd.Tradevalue + ',');
                        sb.Append(trd.Currency + ',');
                        sb.Append(trd.Money);

                        string str = sb.ToString();
                        Invalid.Add(str);
                    }

                    string Epath = @"H:\Desktop\Prj Local\ErrorList.txt";

                    if (File.Exists(Epath))
                    {
                        File.Delete(Epath);               
                    }

                    using (StreamWriter swrite = new StreamWriter(Epath))
                    {
                        foreach (var lines in Invalid)
                        {
                            swrite.WriteLine(lines);
                        }
                    }      
                }



                static void Main(string[] args)
                {
                    Program P = new Program();
                     P.Loaddetails();
                    //Console.WriteLine(Result("CVB000","10/07/2017"));
                    Console.ReadLine();
                }

XML
------


namespace ConsoleApplication12
{    
   [Serializable]
   public  class Trade
    {
        public int tradeid;
        public string tradename;
        public string tradeemail;
        public DateTime tradedate;

    }
}


namespace ConsoleApplication12
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<Trade> lstTd = new List<Trade>();
            XElement xe = XElement.Load(@"H:\Workspace\TEST\test.xml");
            IEnumerable<XElement> iExe=  xe.Elements();

            foreach(var ele in iExe)
            {
                Trade trd = new Trade();
                trd.tradeid = Convert.ToInt32(ele.Element("Id").Value);
                trd.tradename = ele.Element("Name").Value;
                trd.tradeemail = ele.Element("Email").Value;
                trd.tradedate = Convert.ToDateTime(ele.Element("Date").Value);

                lstTd.Add(trd);
            }

            XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
            XmlNode parentNode = xDoc.CreateElement("TradesMain");
            xDoc.AppendChild(parentNode);
            foreach (var trd in lstTd)
            {
                XmlNode secondParentNode = xDoc.CreateElement("Trades");

                XmlNode firstChildNode = xDoc.CreateElement("TradeID");
                firstChildNode.InnerText = trd.tradeid.ToString();
                secondParentNode.AppendChild(firstChildNode);

                XmlNode scChildNode = xDoc.CreateElement("TradeName");
                scChildNode.InnerText = trd.tradename;
                secondParentNode.AppendChild(scChildNode);

                XmlNode trChildNode = xDoc.CreateElement("TradeEmail");
                trChildNode.InnerText = trd.tradeemail;
                secondParentNode.AppendChild(trChildNode);

                XmlNode frChildNode = xDoc.CreateElement("TradeDate");
                frChildNode.InnerText = trd.tradedate.ToString();
                secondParentNode.AppendChild(frChildNode);

                parentNode.AppendChild(secondParentNode);

            }
            xDoc.Save(@"H:\Workspace\TEST\testout.xml");

            Console.WriteLine("ok");

            XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Trade>));

            using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"H:\Workspace\TEST\testserout.xml"))
            {
                ser.Serialize(sw, lstTd);
            }

        }
    }
}



<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
- <Employees> 
- <Employee> 
<Id>1</Id> 
<Name>Sam</Name> 
<Email>Sam@gmail.com</Email> 
<Date>12/24/2013</Date> 
</Employee> 
- <Employee> 
<Id>2</Id> 
<Name>Lucy</Name> 
<Email>Lucy@gmail.com</Email> 
<Date>12/26/2013</Date> 
</Employee> 
- <Employee> 
<Id>3</Id> 
<Name>Kate</Name> 
<Email>Kate@gmail.com</Email> 
<Date>12/27/2013</Date> 
</Employee> 
- <Employee> 
<Id>1</Id> 
<Name>Sam</Name> 
<Email>Sam@gmail.com</Email> 
<Date>12/24/2014</Date> 
</Employee> 
</Employees>
```